# How can i scale up an amazon ec2 instance quickly, in 2-3 mins?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using AWS cloudwatch for scaling my application. I created launch configuration, autoscaling group, upscaling and downscaling alarm and policies. The problem is it is taking 5 mins to launch an instance from an AMI. Is there a way to reduce the start-up time from 5 to 2-3 mins?

Comment: The actual time may depend also on the region. However looks from the basics (don't forget ElasticIP) you have it. AMI is an entire image of the server, so 4-5 minutes sounds normal.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible to speed up the provisioning of a new EC2 instance by an AutoScaling scale up action.

I think it's important to appreciate all that EC2 is doing in those 5 minutes. It's building a new virtual machine, installing an image of an operating system on it, hooking it up to a network and bringing it into service. That's pretty impressive for 5 minutes work if you ask me.

If you're needing to scale up that quickly, then quite frankly you're doing it wrong. Even with autoscaling, you should always be a little over provisioned for your expected load. If you start getting close to that over scaled limit, then it's time to autoscale up. Don't provision exactly what you need, it won't work well.

Answer (score 0):

The start up time depends on a few things:

1. The availability of resources for your instance type within the
   availability zone.
2. The size of the AMI. In the case of a custom AMI image, it may need to be copied to the correct internal storage for the VM.
3. Initialization procedures. For windows, some images with user-data scripts can require a reboot to join the domain.

This is an old question, and as I have seen. Start times have improved for EC2 over the past years. Some providers like Google Cloud can provide servers in under a minute. So if your workload is that demanding, you may research the available providers and their operational differences.